# Is there a difference in the timestamp formats used by iOS and PHP?

Tags: php, ios, datetime, formatting, unix-timestamp

I got some of the timestamps from the consolidated.db on my iPhone (the one from the location tracking 'scandal' recently). I made a little PHP page to convert them to nicely formatted dates then output a list, but I'm getting dates from 1980.

Do they use a different system? Or does consolidated.db have incorrect data?

Example timestamp: 316777502
My code: `$date = date("t M Y", $timestamp);`

Comment: Are you sure there aren't any negative timestamps? Please share one that shows 1935.

Comment: Sorry, I just checked that, it was some incorrect data that got added when I was writing the script that reads the database. All the others are from 1980, and I've had my iPhone almost exactly a year, so I was thinking maybe it was a 30 year offset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I found an article that details a manual process by which it is possible to view the data:

http://dropstones.blogspot.com/2011/04/extracting-iphone-ios4-location-data-in.html

According to that article, the timestamps are not traditional timestamps of the number of seconds from 1/1/1970, but are instead based on the number of seconds from 1/1/2001 (so, there is a 31 year offset). I cannot confirm whether this is true, but if we follow the assumption that it is, we have to add the number of seconds in 31 years (978264705) to the timestamp to change it to a traditional timestamp giving the number of seconds from 1/1/1970. The line you posted would therefore be replaced with this:

```
$timestamp += 978264705;
$date = date("t M Y", $timestamp);
```

Comment: I discovered soon after asking this that they are in fact from 2001. Thanks for your help, looks like a good article. Hope this page can now help the next guy to encounter this.

Comment: It did help the next guy... :)